# Timeline doesn't work when reading from a .csv file

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I am trying to implement a timeline with a brush using Mike Bostock's code over [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537).

The code that I have can be found over [here](https://codepen.io/hira00/pen/dmwxJO) on a CodePen link.

Inside the function `drawTimeline`, I am defining a variable data (from line 19-23) that takes in the first seven values of my `.csv` file. The issue I am having is that even though the code works fine when I hardcode the variable data (on line 24), it doesn't work when I use it by pushing in the first seven values inside an array I create. I've used `console.log` to print the values outside and they seem to be identical in format to the ones that I hardcode, and yet the timeline doesn't show anything in the case of the csv-derived array. Could anyone please help with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timeline **is** working. The problem is just the time span.

When you hardcode the data, you have this domain (I'm in Australia, you may see different times according to your time zone):

```
[Fri Jan 19 2018 20:36:02 GMT+1100, Thu Jan 25 2018 20:36:02 GMT+1100]
```

This domain has almost one week in the time span. On the other hand, when you push the first 7 values, this is the domain:

```
[Tue Mar 06 2018 21:52:42 GMT+1100, Tue Mar 06 2018 23:55:30 GMT+1100]
```

As you can see, just a couple of hours. But it is a correct domain, so the chart should work. What's happening here?

The problem is that you set this for the ticks:

```
.ticks(d3.timeDay)
```

Obviously, there is just a couple of hours in that domain, not days.

**Solution**:

Remove your `ticks` method.

Here is the updated CodePen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMxzGM?editors=0010